# Is there any way to check whether header file included directly or indirectly in single compilation unit for gcc?

Tags: gcc, gcc-plugins

```
// a.cc  
#include "a.h"
```

```
// a.h  
#include "b.h"  
#include "c.h"
```

```
// b.h  
#include "c.h"
```

```
// c.h
#include <string>
```

"b.h" is being processed directly by current compliation unit
"c.h"  is being processed indirectly by "gcc -H"

I want to prevents developers from including "c.h" directly in "a.cc".A way to specify some metadata rules by cmake/gcc, like bazel

gcc has plugin event "PLUGIN_INCLUDE_FILE", Unfortunately, the information provided, unlike clang, is not sufficient to do this, (maybe I didn't find it)

P.S. I want to do something like bazel layercheck(https://bazel.build/reference/be/c-cpp#hdrs )(clang -fmodules-decluse blabla...), using cmake and gcc toolchain
P.S. "xx.h" and "xx.cc" is component unit if the same base name

Comment: If you reference something from c.h in a.cc, shouldn't you get an error if it's not included (explicitly or implicitly)?

Comment: like this example in bazel. https://bazel.build/reference/be/c-cpp#hdrs

Answer (score 1):

Command line option [`-H`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-H) causes gcc print the name of each header file included.

Automatically generated `.d` header dependency files also contain full paths of all files included for a `.o` file.

---

> i want to prevents developers from including "c.h" directly in "a.cc"

You can use the same method gcc uses for this purpose. E.g. [/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/include/avx2intrin.h](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=blob;f=gcc/config/i386/avx2intrin.h;h=9b8c13b7233873d5ba76c1a399cdf1db641f98ce;hb=08b887fd41c0cf2b14a8d8cda21d86f2c991f606#l24):

```
#ifndef _IMMINTRIN_H_INCLUDED
# error "Never use <avx2intrin.h> directly; include <immintrin.h> instead."
#endif
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but this will exclude headers already included indirectly. for example , "a.h" include "b.h" and "c.h" , "b.h" include "c.h", no way to know "a.h" include "c.h" directly

Comment: I've already tried,You can try. It won't work

Comment: I updated the case

Comment: You can read it here. bazel.build/reference/be/c-cpp#hdrs